# Extending the stay beyond dates mentioned in the Schengen visa application

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

In the Schengen visa application, we've mentioned that we'll travel to Iceland for 7 days. However, the visa issued is for almost a month's duration.

We're returning from Iceland via Switzerland (layover as per original plans), but since the visa is valid for a month, we thought it would be nice to travel Switzerland for 3 days. Would this be a problem considering in the application we said our trip would be for 7 days only?

Comment: Are you sure it is valid for a month? Often it is the requested time in a longer period, which might be the month.

Comment: @Willeke Just confirmed once again, It is from 30/04/24 until 24/05/24 and the "duration of stay" is 8

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As you mention in your comment, duration of stay is 8 days.
This means that in period of 30th of April till the 24th of May you are allowed to be in the Schengen area 8 days.
And a day in this case is any time on a calendar day. If you arrive at five minutes before midnight that counts as a whole day.
And it does include all of the Schengen area, so if you fly from Iceland to Switzerland at the end of your 7 days in Iceland, you will have to leave the Schengen area before midnight the next day.

So no, you did not get a visa for a month, you got the option to move your week a bit forward or back, and one extra day in case something happens.

Best to keep to the plan you made, on which they awarded you the visa.

Comment: Even if it was technically legal (which it is not, as your answer explains), it would be unwise, because they would see that your answers were not congruent with your subsequent behavior. Visa officers usually do not like it when that happens.